# Comparing attribute of an anchor's href with "#"?

Tags: javascript, html, css, href

I want to change the css properties of all anchors with href set to "#".

```
<div class="mlItems">
    <a href="#">Home</a>
</div>
<div class="mlItems">
    <a href="applets.html">Applets</a>
</div>
<div class="mlItems">
    <a href="tools.html">Tools</a>
</div>
<div class="mlItems">
    <a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a>
</div>
<div class="mlItems">
    <a href="tutorials.html">Tutorials</a>
</div>
<div class="mlItems">
     <a href="fun.html">Fun</a>
</div>
<div class="mlItems">
      <a href="about.html">About</a>
</div>
```

so i searched the elements using their tag name and compare the href with "#" using a for loop. Then changed the style properties of the element using javascript.

```
function setnavstat(){
var menul = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for(var i = 0;i < menul.lenght;i++){
    if(menul[i].getAttribute("href") == "#"){ 
         menul[i].style.color = "#000000";
       } 
     }
}
```

but this doesn't seem to work. help me. thanks in advance. it would help if the response be in JavaScript only.

Comment: Are you calling `setnavstat()`?

Comment: First issue - typo. `menul.lenght` should be `menul.length`. Actually, that's the whole issue. Voting to close.

Comment: You can use CSS (pseudo attributes) -> a[href="#"] { color: #000; }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use JavaScript, you can do it in pure CSS :

```css
a[href="#"]{
    color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<div class="mlItems">
    <a href="#">Home</a>
</div>
<div class="mlItems">
    <a href="applets.html">Applets</a>
</div>
<div class="mlItems">
    <a href="tools.html">Tools</a>
</div>
<div class="mlItems">
    <a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a>
</div>
<div class="mlItems">
    <a href="tutorials.html">Tutorials</a>
</div>
<div class="mlItems">
     <a href="fun.html">Fun</a>
</div>
<div class="mlItems">
      <a href="about.html">About</a>
</div>
```